Free a Python library using TCL
In Python I load a library (pyd). But I need to unload it before a second call.
In Python I get this done with:
import ctypes, _ctypes

dll = ctypes.CDLL('path_to_file')
try:
    _ctypes.FreeLibrary(dll._handle)
    _ctypes.FreeLibrary(dll._handle)
except:
    pass

I know the FREE_LIBRARY is part of twapi, but how do I do this in TCL ?
I'm not a TCL guru, so any help would be great.

Welcome! What are you trying to achieve >in< Tcl, exactly? Please show Tcl code

Tcl can unload shared libraries loaded with load if the OS supports such a concept. It can't do a thing with libraries loaded with python.

Also, unloading a library that hasn't been fully unhooked first is a recipe for disaster (crashes, etc). That's why Tcl's unload only enables for a library if it specifically includes the (documented) unloading hook; it's just not safe otherwise.

FWIW: FreeLibrary is Windows-specific. It’s not safe to actually unload the DLL this way in Python, as ctypes still holds a reference to the DLL. You could call FreeLibrary from TCL in the same way, with the same lack of safety.

Tcl has a built-in command, unload, that can undo what load does and remove a library from the process. It's very rarely used, as it only enables for a particular library when that library defines a callback function for disentangling itself from the process (deleting commands it created, etc.) and writing those is quite tricky. Without that deliberate disentangling step, you'd get dangling code pointer and data pointers in various places, and a crash would likely ensue. Almost all extension libraries don't bother supporting that; the ones that do support it probably ought to document that as it is a rare capability.
Note that Tcl doesn't support loading and unloading arbitrary libraries at the script layer. There is some support for more than that in C, but that's mainly so libraries can load their internal non-Tcl dependencies. (It's used by the ODBC driver for example.)

The Tcl library itself is unloadable, though not from Tcl itself. If you are going to do it, you need to call Tcl_Finalize() before doing so; that shuts down process global systems like the IO buffers, filesystem caches, memory management engine core and several worker threads. It's probably a good idea to delete any interpreters you have open first.
That API isn't commonly used, but is sometimes used when looking for memory allocation bugs, as otherwise things that are held indefinitely can look like leaks (they're not, they just don't change much).
